# How to update array value in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, database

How to update array in MongoDb?

This is my shell script I want to update fileInfo using this script some product have fileInfo exist and some product have
fileInfo not exist.

So my requrement is if fileInfo exist it will updated and if fileInfo not exist it will create

What modification will taken my code?Thankyou

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d460721cdb5a4b0a73d4ba"),
    "catId" : "56d4558b1cdb5a4b0a73d03b",
    "pname" : "ABCName",
    "brand" : "ABCBrand",
    "actualPrice" : "19",
    "offer" : 0,   
    "shopId" : "56d312a61cdb5a1a2d8045",
    "mProId" : "569e04ecd08598371ebe53eb",
    "del" : "N",
    "createdOn" : "28-Feb-2016 19:29:29 UTC"
}
```

adding data is this one in every file

```
"fileInfo" : [
        {
            "versionId" : "BHpKOLlsgIRF7JqcBrKLPDFC5OgUAUEp",
            "fileKey" : "productFile/abc.jpg"
        }
    ],
```

This is my shell script code

```
var product = currentDb.getCollection("product");

var shop_id = "56d312a61cdb5a1a2d8045";

var mproductData = mproduct.find();
var productData = product.find({shopId:shop_id});
var productData1 = product.find({shopId:shop_id}).count();

var count=0;
var mcount=0;
for(var i=0;i<mproductData.length();i++)
{
    mcount++ 
    for(var j=0;j<productData.length();j++)
    {

    if(mproductData[i]._id==productData[j].mProId)
    {            
            count++;
            var mpro_id = mproductData[i]._id;
            var mfile_version = mproductData[i].fileInfo[0].versionId; 
        var mfile_key = mproductData[i].fileInfo[0].fileKey;     
        print(mpro_id);
        print(mfile_info);
        print(mfile_key);
            if(mproductData[i]._id==productData[j].mProId)
    {            
            count++;
            var mpro_id = mproductData[i]._id;
            var mfile_version = mproductData[i].fileInfo[0].versionId; 
        var mfile_key = mproductData[i].fileInfo[0].fileKey;     
        print(mpro_id);
        print(mfile_info);
        print(mfile_key);
        product.update({"mProId":''+mpro_id+''},{"$set": {"fileInfo" : [{"versionId" : ''+mfile_info+'',"fileKey" : ''+mfile_key+''}]}};

    }
    }        
}
```

Comment: We are here to help you, but not to do your assignments or homework. If you don't know programming, just google and read documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
db.collection.update({},{$set: {"fileInfo" : [
       {
            "versionId" : "BHpKOLlsgIRF7JqcBrKLPDFC5OgUAUEp",
            "fileKey" : "productFile/abc.jpg"
       }
]}},{multi:true})
```

This will create `fileInfo` property if it doesn't exist, otherwise simply update it

Comment: I don't have full context, so can't replicate your code and environment on my machine. I'll suggest look and compare what are you doing  `product.update` and compare it with my solution. are they looking same?

Comment: you see my js code actually rhis fileInfo is a sample data i want to update versionId and fileKey depends on the mproduct.So each time it will changed when i used you code in my script it shows an error unexpected token

Comment: replace db.collection with `product`. I believe you are using it as it is.

Comment: No Sir I am uisng in correctly this is my updated one

Comment: if(mproductData[i]._id==productData[j].mProId)
        {            
                count++;
                var mpro_id = mproductData[i]._id;
                var mfile_version = mproductData[i].fileInfo[0].versionId; 
            var mfile_key = mproductData[i].fileInfo[0].fileKey;     
            print(mpro_id);
            print(mfile_info);
            print(mfile_key);
                product.update({"mProId":''+mpro_id+''},{"$set": {"fileInfo.$.versionId":''+mfile_version+'',"fileInfo.$.fileKey":''+mfile_key+''}});

Comment: don't copy your code here, update your post instead.

Comment: **Sir** help me to i am new in this area

Comment: First, you code event doesn't have matching closing braces, second, you didn't updated code, where is `{multi:true}`, third, I have no clue what you code is doing in some many loops?

Comment: Again, this forum is helping you to find a solution, not to solve your assignments or homework. So go back and read your code, debug it and try to find what are you doing wrong?

Comment: I undesrstood Sir got it